На чём писать проверку устройств/портов материнской платы UEFI
Дано: efi-shell и программная среда для написания и отладки efi-приложений (edk2); материнская плата неопределённой комплектации.
Необходимо опросить все устройства и сокеты материнской платы, доступные из-под efi-shell, и составить отчёт об ответах. Под устройством следует понимать как распаянные порты: USB, COM, PCI, SATA, Ethernet  т.д. так и не прошедшие распайку на конкретной плате.
Вопрос: Возможно ли это в заданных условиях? Если да, в какую сторону (в какую библиотеку/протокол/чисто на скриптах и обработке логов) копать?
